# Cakephp 2 - Most simple associations

Tags: cakephp, relationship

I'm facing trouble telling cake the most simple associations.

I have two Models:

1. CoreUser.php
2. CoreRole.php

.

**One User** has **one Role**.

How to assign that in cake? (HasOne or BelongsTo? => When to choose what?)

What to put in what Model? I tried both and ever end up with a recursion-error or it is just not working.

**My SQL-Tables:**

(*tbl*) core_users [id,username,password,role_id]

(*tbl*) core_roles [id,name]

**My Models:**

---

```
class CoreUser extends AppModel {

public $hasOne = array(
        'Role' => array(
            'className' => 'CoreRole',
            'foreignKey' => 'id'
        )
    );
}
```

---

```
class CoreRole extends AppModel {

public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'CoreUser',
            'foreignKey' => 'role_id'
        )
    );
}
```

---

**=>** Can you give me the correct code i need to insert into one of both (or both) models to tell cake about the relationship?

Thanks in advance

Comment: to make it more clear tell the scenario what you want to achieve, By this i can only say that most of work is given in cake documentation check the cake documentation Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, there are two things you need to think about, one of them being non-Cakephp specific.

**A. Relationships:** A relationship is always bidirectional. When determining the relationship between two Models/Objects/Tables, you always ask two questions:

> 1. How many instances of B are related to one instance of A?
> 2. How many instances of A are related to one instance of B?

You've said, One user has one Role. However, One Role has how many Users related to it? That will tell you the complete relationship between a User and a Role. (Apologies for the digression but this is important and I'm referencing [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1418835935).)

**B. Difference between hasMany and belongsTo:**
This is determined based on the direction of traversing a relationship.
Based on point A, say you've determined that:
One User has one Role **but One Role has many Users.**

Now when you are in the User's model trying to fetch related Role data, you need to define the following in the User model:

```
class CoreUser extends AppModel {
  public $belongsTo = array(
    'Role' => array(
       'className' => 'CoreRole',
       'foreignKey' => 'role_id'
    )
  );
}
```

But when you are in the Role's model and trying to fetch related User data, you will need to define the following in the Role model:

```
class CoreRole extends AppModel {
  public $hasMany = array(
    'User' => array(
       'className' => 'CoreUser',
       'foreignKey' => 'role_id'
    )
  );
}
```

For a full discussion refer to [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/152731/what-is-the-main-difference-between-has-many-and-belongs-to-relationship-in-mysq).

Comment: Hi Thanks, thats what i always tried but it throws me that error:  Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Comment: I updated my Code for you to review my Model-Relations as u suggested.   This throws the subscribed Error when going on a $this->CoreUser->find('all') in Controller

Comment: Can u tell me more than "User hasOne Role"? e. g. the $hasOne would be interesting, since i seem to misset the foreignKey (its only linked via FKs in one direction but cake searches boths ways for a user_id in CoreRole)

Comment: I realised your problem: If Role hasMany Users (instead of Role hasOne User), then it is correct to say User belongsTo Role instead of User hasOne Role. I've edited my answer to factor this bit in. This is why I was telling you to define the relationship completely (ie both ways).